# $k[x^{1/2},x^{1/4},x^{1/8},...]/(x)$ is not noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, noetherian

> Let $R$ be a non-trivial commutative ring. If $R$ has only one prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$, is $R$ Noetherian?

As pointed out in the comments, this affirmation is false. E.g., take $k[x^{1/2},x^{1/4},x^{1/8},...]/(x)$, where $k$ is a field, as a counterexample. However, it is still not clear to me why.

Can anyone please show me the (single) prime ideal in $k[x^{1/2},x^{1/4},x^{1/8},...]/(x)$ and proof that it is not noetherian?

Comment: [Any non-Noetherian local ring with nil Jacobson radical is a counterexample.](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=23&H=22&L=64l)

Comment: To address your edit, the only prime ideal is $(x^{1/2},x^{1/4},x^{1/8}, \dots)$. It is not Noetherian since $(x^{1/2}) \subset (x^{1/4}) \subset (x^{1/8}) \subset \dots$

Comment: In order to connect your question to the answer notice that $k[x^{1/2},x^{1/4},x^{1/8},...]$ is isomorphic to $$k[x,x_1,\dots,x_n,\dots]/(x-x_1^2,\dots,x-x_n^{2^n},\dots).$$ Then $k[x^{1/2},x^{1/4},x^{1/8},...]/(x)$ is isomorphic to $$k[x_1,\dots,x_n,\dots]/(x_1^2,\dots,x_n^{2^n},\dots).$$

Answer (score 4):

$k[x_1, x_2, ... ] / (x_1^2, x_2^2,  ... )$ where $k$ is a field is a counterexample. Any prime ideal must contain $(x_1, x_2, ...)$ so there is only one prime ideal. However, that ring is not Noetherian.

Comment: If one changes this well known example into $k[x_1, x_2, ... ] / (x_1^2, x_2^{2^2},  ... )$, then one gets the ring that the OP mentioned.

Comment: However, there is no indication about why these rings are not noetherian, which makes this answer incomplete.